# Blazor WebAssembly progressive web app Cannot call API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created the Blazor WebAssembly progressive web app in .NET 6.0 and my API is .NET 5.0
then send the request to the API my request is not sent to the API.following is my API calling code. can you tell me what is wrong?

```
 public async Task<List<ModCompanySettingQuery>> Fnc_Fetch_CompanyList(ModApiLogin l_ModApiLogin)
{
    try

    {
        List<ModCompanySettingQuery> l_ListModCompanySettingQuery;
        string l_result;
        using (HttpClient l_HttpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            l_HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("URL of api");
            l_HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

            string l_jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l_ModApiLogin);
            StringContent l_StringContent = new StringContent(l_jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage l_HttpResponseMessage = await l_HttpClient.PostAsync("Login/Post", l_StringContent);
            //HttpResponseMessage l_HttpResponseMessage = await l_HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Login/Post", l_ModApiLogin);
        //yha sy agy ni chal rha
         l_result = await l_HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        l_ListModCompanySettingQuery = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ModCompanySettingQuery>>(l_result);
        if (l_ListModCompanySettingQuery == null)
        {
            l_ListModCompanySettingQuery = new List<ModCompanySettingQuery>();
        }
        return l_ListModCompanySettingQuery;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image: when a sent request from postman data comes correctly]

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check the value of `URL of api`, whether contains `apiUser`. Just make sure the request url is correct.
2. Please set the breakpoint in this line

   ```
   HttpResponseMessage l_HttpResponseMessage = await l_HttpClient.PostAsync("Login/Post", l_StringContent);
   ```

   You also can check the request url and other information.
3. You can try to change below code

   ```
   l_HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
   ```

   to

   ```
   l_HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header
   ```

The third suggest should useful to you, if it not works. You should use Fiddler tools capture the request information.

For this issue, I think we don't need to collect the inforamtion for api server side.

Comment: thanks for reply @jason pan i resoled this issue by removing <form> tag in UI